# Create Flag Column based off of multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a flag column based off if the description column contains 'Hello' and 'Name' key words and if call_duration is 2 min or less. If both conditions are met flag would be '1', else it would be '0'.

Data example

| Description | Call_Duration |
| --- | --- |
| Hello, my name | 1 |
| Contact error | 42 |
| Hello, my name | 3 |

Output should be

| Description | Call_Duration | Flag_Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello, my name | 1 | 1 |
| Contact error | 42 | 0 |
| Hello, my name | 3 | 0 |

Below is my code i'm currently using

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.txt', sep=',')

df['call_duration'] = df['call_duration_sec']/60

df.call_duration = df.call_duration.round()

# Adding flag column based off key words in Description column
df['Flag_Column'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains("hello&name", case=False, na=False) , 1, 0)

# print(df.head())


df.to_csv('some_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to check for hello and name, separated by any other text.  Combine this w/the duration, and use np.where to generate the flag.

If hello and name could be in the opposite order, I'd suggest checking out how regular expressions work and play around w/building your own.

```
import numpy as np
df['Flag_Column'] = np.where((df['Description'].str.contains('hello.*name', case=False) & df['Call_Duration'].le(2)), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Works exactly how i needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple conditions using `&` like this:

```
df['Flag_Column'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains("hello.*name", case=False, na=False, regex=True) & (df['Call_Duration'] < 2), 1, 0)
```

.contains also needs `regex=True` to find any occurrence of `hello<anyNumberOfCharactersHere>name`